# How do I import data and packages from REST APIs

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, rest, coursera-api

I'm currently trying to learn Python through coursera and I'm trying to run the code but I'm running into an error when I try to install nba_api. Below I have pasted my code

```
!pip install nba_api  

# I get an 'invalid syntax error' here ^^  

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x={'a':[11,21,31],'b':[12,22,32]}

print(x)

df=pd.DataFrame(x)
print(type(df))

print(df.head())

from nba_api.stats.static import teams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong/missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a shorthand for calling out to the shell that is only in the REPL. You can't use this in Python files.

Instead you should put your code in a package and have a dependency on nba_api, when someone installs your package, nba_api package would also be installed.